# 360 degree panorama street view in iOS from google map sdk

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to show [***this***](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@53.426398,-2.242795,3a,75y,213h,90t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1sshcQTg4Y9qh9T0p5aspVvA!2e0!3e2!6m1!1e1) location inside the map with out using Google Maps URL Scheme.I used GMSPanoramaView for showing street view by using given lat/long ***(53.426398,-2.242795)*** but inside building area not showing , that area is showing in browser or  URL Scheme.

I used [***github demo***](https://github.com/ratana/streetview-panorama-demo) code to show street view but I want to show exactly above location inside app.

I dont want to use webview ,safari or google map app.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing

```
[panoramaView_ moveToPanoramaID:@"i3XJvXkmgNMAAAQW-ezYnQ"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Download the pano or use one of the many Google approved ways to obtain the view.

Here's an alternate link (used Embedder for Google Business View)
https://maps.google.com/maps?layer=c&panoid=shcQTg4Y9qh9T0p5aspVvA&ie=UTF8&source=embed&output=svembed&cbp=13%2C213%2C%2C0%2C0

Grab the pano using Pano Fetch

Use the API - The below is partially psudo code, You'll require a small amount of Javascript knowledge.

```
var your_pano = new google.maps.LatLng(53.426398,-2.242795);
  var panoramaOptions2 = {
    position: your_pano,
        addressControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
    },
    zoomControl: false,
    linksControl: true,
    panControl: false,
    fov: 110,
    pov: {
      heading: 100,
      pitch: -20
    },
    zoom: 0
  };
  var your_pano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('your_pano'),
      panoramaOptions2);
  your_pano.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: i already createed panorama in ios from google map street view but some inside building location is not showing in google map. ex :- https://www.google.com/maps/@28.575714,77.23906,3a,75y,142.82h,90t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1s4TkSok0otb8AAAAGOuK4Hw!2e0!3e2 . we can only put lat long in but here some extra field is given in url like 3a,75y,142.82h,90t. I thing u r not getting .Pls let me know in case of any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible! Extract the `panoid` from [user2744623's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24068332/2094275):

> Here's an alternate link (used Embedder for Google Business View) https://maps.google.com/maps?layer=c&panoid=shcQTg4Y9qh9T0p5aspVvA&ie=UTF8&source=embed&output=svembed&cbp=13%2C213%2C%2C0%2C0

And then use it as a `PanoramaID` in the iOS SDK:

```
GMSPanoramaView *view_ = [GMSPanoramaView panoramaWithFrame:CGRectZero
                          nearCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.426398, -2.242795)];
[view_ moveToPanoramaID:@"shcQTg4Y9qh9T0p5aspVvA"];
```

You can then set `GMSPanoramaCamera:cameraWithHeading:pitch:zoom:` to whichever angle you prefer:

```
[GMSPanoramaCamera cameraWithHeading:200.0f pitch:-10.0f zoom:1];
```

[Here's the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_panorama_view#ae75d51fad3a572a98dc16822be371c7d) on `GMSPanoramaView:moveToPanoramaID:`:

> Requests a panorama with `panoramaID`.
>   Upon successful completion `panoramaView:didMoveToPanorama:` will be sent to `GMSPanoramaViewDelegate`. On error `panoramaView:error:onMoveToPanoramaID:` will be sent. Repeated calls to `moveToPanoramaID:` result in the previous pending (incomplete) transitions being cancelled -- only the most recent of `moveNearCoordinate:` and `moveToPanoramaId:` will proceed and generate events. Only `panoramaID`s obtained from the Google Maps SDK for iOS are supported.

I think you can ignore the last sentence, heh.

Here's a complete-ish implementation, adapted from the SDK demo project:

```c
@interface PanoramaViewController () <GMSPanoramaViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation PanoramaViewController {
    GMSPanoramaView *view_;
    BOOL configured_;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    view_ = [GMSPanoramaView panoramaWithFrame:CGRectZero
                                nearCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.426398, -2.242795)];
    view_.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    view_.delegate = self;
    self.view = view_;

    [view_ moveToPanoramaID:@"shcQTg4Y9qh9T0p5aspVvA"];
}

#pragma mark - GMSPanoramaDelegate

- (void)panoramaView:(GMSPanoramaView *)view
   didMoveToPanorama:(GMSPanorama *)panorama {
    if (!configured_) {
        view_.camera = [GMSPanoramaCamera cameraWithHeading:200.0f pitch:-10.0f zoom:1];

        configured_ = YES;
    }
}

// Use to fine-tune initial heading and pitch
- (void)panoramaView:(GMSPanoramaView *)panoramaView
       didMoveCamera:(GMSPanoramaCamera *)camera {
    NSLog(@"Camera: (%f,%f,%f)", camera.orientation.heading, camera.orientation.pitch, camera.zoom);
}

// Helpful in finding other panorama IDs or debugging:
- (void)panoramaView:(GMSPanoramaView *)view
willMoveToPanoramaID:(NSString *)panoramaID {
    NSLog(@"willMoveToPanoramaID: %@", panoramaID);
}

- (void)panoramaView:(GMSPanoramaView *)view
               error:(NSError *)error
  onMoveToPanoramaID:(NSString *)panoramaID {
    NSLog(@"error: %@ onMoveToPanoramaID: %@", error, panoramaID);
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank u very much I forgot   [view_ moveToPanoramaID:@"shcQTg4Y9qh9T0p5aspVvA"];    thanks alot